# JCE editor in Joomla removes link from a div

Tags: html, joomla, hyperlink

When I create a div with a link, and I toggle the editor, JCE removes the entire link code from the div.

This is the example:

```
<a href="#"><div id="test">text or image here</div></a>
```

When I toggle editor to see the result, and than back to the code view, this is the result:

```
<div id="test">text or image here </div>
```

So I don't understand why JCE removes the link outside of the div. I put there the link cause I would like the entire div with its background to be clickable.

If I save the article, when I'm in the code view, it saves the link! So it remove this only if I change to the visual way when I'm editing the article.

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` is a block element and `<a>` is an inline element ahd before HTML5  putting a block inside of any inline element was not valid. This is why I suspect that JCE would wipe it out; in pre HTML5 this would be invalid markup.  In HTML5 you can put a block element inside of `<a>` it, but I'm not sure if there is a setting in JCE to get it to validate with HTML5. You should probably ask on their forums.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct) gives you some more detail.